# finding javascript errors from external page, output results to file

Tags: javascript, php, debugging, console.log

I have been tasked to created a script that is performing health checks on a web page,

for the most part I can get the information I need using cURL and a couple of other tools.

So this is the set up.

I have a php class on Server A, a cron job on this server executes a php script that begins the health check by loading a page on Server B, using cURL i can get timeout information, response codes etc, but I am stuck when it comes to discovering if the given web page has Javascript errors (that would appear in the console); and i would really appreciate any help that anyone could give.

Is there a way to make an API call via PHP that would contact a page on Server B, load that page, then load the any error console entries into a text file?

These details are available via any browser, is it the browser that generates these errors or can I use a script that will fool the script into thinking its a browser and grab the errors?

I really could do with any help!

Thank you.

Comment: Javascript is interpreted by the browser, it's a real-time process and I don't believe PHP is capable of doing what you're asking. The best you could do is perhaps make the javascript send errors it runs into to the server via AJAX, there's a few tools to help with that. Remember that each browser might have different support for Javascript too, there's no 'definite' errors, as the browser is what decides if there's a problem or not.

Comment: @voltlight Thanks for that comment, yeah i know they are both sides of the server and I have been looking into firing an ajax request when an error is detected, the problem being is that you are right about browser issuers, the method that is supposed to work (window.onerror, does pretty much bugger all when an error is introduced, or is unexpected - which begs the question, what are you supposed to do with unexpected errors... sighs

Answer (score 2):

In javascript you can use phantom.js to read console message.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
  console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};
```

source : http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html

Comment: Thank you @antonin-bouscarel  I am hoping that this will give me what I need!